# A safer way to return a generic indicator object indicating failure

Tags: java, type-safety

I'm writing a singly-linked list that implements the `List` interface. I decided going in that I'd try to implement every method as an exercise; even the optional ones.

I started writing the `ListIterator`, and found the need to return the node previous to a given node for operations like `add`. Unfortunately, I didn't anticipate this scenario prior to writing the rest of the list, and have no way of indicating failure (failure being that the given node doesn't exist in the list), since null is a valid return if the root node is supplied. I decided to allow the caller to pass in an indicator node that would be returned if the node wasn't found. I wasn't sure the best way to handle this thought, since `Node` is generic.

I ended up making the indicator of type `Node<Object>`, and casting it prior to returning. I know this is dangerous though, so I made it very clear in the documentation that the method isn't safe (plus, of course, it's `private`).

I'd like to know if there's a less hack-ish way of dealing with this scenario though.

I didn't think including the full implementation was necessary. The names should be obvious enough (I hope).

```
/**
 * Dangerous.
 * Returns the node that comes before the given node, or badNode if the
 *  node doesn't exist in the list.
 * The return must be checked against badNode prior to use!
 *  
 * @param node The node to find the predecessor of 
 * @param badNode The indicator that will be returned if node isn't in the list
 * @return The predecessor of node, or badNode if node doesn't exist.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Node<E> getNodeBefore(Node<E> node, Node<Object> badNode) {
    Node<E> curNode = getRootNode();
    Node<E> prevNode = null;

    while (curNode != null) {
        if (curNode == node) {
            return prevNode;
        }

    prevNode = curNode;
    curNode = curNode.getNextNode();
    }

    return (Node<E>)badNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly clean way is to use Optionals, like [these](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) or [those](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html). So you would make `getNodeBefore` return an `Optional<Node<E>>`.

The `badNode` idea is, hm, exotic to me.

Comment: I started using `Optional`s for everything to the point of abuse after coming from Haskell, , so I limited myself. I think you're right though, this is a legitimate use case. And like I said,  `null` is already a valid return if the root node is given, so I needed an alternative. If Java supported pattern matching, and had a viable `Either` type, that might have worked too.

Comment: @Carcigenicate right, I removed the bit about `null`s. Should have read more carefully. While `Optional` may be overused, I think it's still better. Another possibility would be a static method in `Node` class, something like `Node.<E>absent()` that would return a `Node<E>` instance enwrapping null. You could implement a private `isAbsent` flag in `Node` and use it ensure (in `equals` and `hashcode` implementations) that `Node.absent()` is always considered different from any other `Node` instance, but always equal to another `absent()`. Absent, none, whatever other term. Emulated Either!

Comment: Ahh! I didn't think of just wrapping a null with the node. Still a little dangerous since I wouldn't otherwise expect a null to enter the list (although it isn't enforced), but still better than the cast I'm currently using. And I've tried the flag idea in the past, and I didn't like the result. It felt clumsy to me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, nevermind about the dangerous part. If I modify the `toString` method, elements will never be directly used internally.